# Repo command with no results

Tags: android, git, repository

I have installed repo and git on my PC. I am trying to get the latest Android source by using the following commands:

1. `repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git`
   The command succeeds but I am not able to see .repo directory created.
2. repo sync
   This command also succeeds and the program shows the details of objects being received. However I am not able to see anything downloaded to my PC.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

.repo is a hidden directory.
Does repo init says succeeded and initialized in dir path?

You can see the contents only after sync is complete.

Comment: Thanks. It does say succeeded. I did not wait for sync to complete because it was taking very long and I could not see even a single file copied to my PC. Are you saying that no files will be visible till sync is 100% complete?

Comment: Yes, you should wait till repo sync is complete.

Comment: True, `.repo` is a hidden directory. And most of the operations by `repo sync` is performed in the hidden directory. However the last parts of the process should be visible on your filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your git installation folders, or the directory where you have launched the command. Usually the contents are just downloaded in the current working directory in a folder.